# Is there a reason to use the XML::LibXML::Number-object in my XML::LibXML-example?

Tags: perl, xml-libxml

In this example I get to times '96'. Is there a possible case where I would need a XML::LibXML-Number-object to to achieve the goal?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings; use strict;
use 5.012;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml_string =<<EOF;
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<filesystem>
   <path>
     <dirname>/var</dirname>
     <files>
       <action>delete</action>
       <age units="hours">10</age>
     </files>
     <files>
       <action>delete</action>
       <age units="hours">96</age>
     </files>
   </path>
</filesystem>
EOF
#/

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( string => $xml_string );
my $root = $doc->documentElement;

my $result = $root->find( '//files/age[@units="hours"]' );
$result = $result->get_node( 1 );
say ref $result; # XML::LibXML::Element
say $result->textContent; # 96

$result =  $root->find ( 'number( //files/age[@units="hours"] )' );
say ref $result; # XML::LibXML::Number
say $result; # 96
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve, and perhaps give a smaller example of what goes wrong?

Comment: In this case it doesn't go anything wrong - I am searching an example with a XML::LibXML::Number-object which can convince me, that there is an need for the XML::LibXML::Number-object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I've used XML::LibXML quite a bit I have never encountered the XML::LibXML::Number class.  It seems to exist to allow XPath expressions to make numerical assertions about the text content of a node (e.g.: > 10).

If all you want is the number '96' then the easiest way is probably:

```
my $result = $root->findvalue( '//files/age[@units="hours"]' );
```

An idiom I find useful for getting multiple values is:

```
my @values = map { $_->to_literal } $doc->find('//files/age');
```